# Есть ли аналог с++ Builder под Linux?

Tags: linux

Есть ли аналог с++ Builder под Linux? И работают ли в нем API типа IntToStr и т.п.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IntToStr не зависит от IDE (с++ Bilder'а). IDE есть к примеру Eclipse c модулем для c++, Anjuta и т.п.

Comment: Насколько мне известно, функция IntToStr - это именно борландовская непереносимая вещь. В стандарте С++ предусмотрены другие механизмы перевода числовых типов в строки.

Answer (score 4):

Аналогов нет. И не надо.

Answer (score 3):

Для разработки кода на C++ в Linux есть удобные среды:
QtCreator
Eclipse

Answer (score 0):

Qt, и еще пачка опен сурсных проектов. да и компилятор самый самый - gcc.